# Adding Images in a TableView in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I tried to add images with the size of 32 by 32...it worked but it shows me only the first image for all the objects on the table view... In other words only image for all the other objects

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row` delegate method.  You should probably read the [TableView Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TableView/Concepts/AboutTables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000115-CJBCADCE) before going further.

Comment: I use the following line of code:

UIImage * image; 
 switch (indexPath.section) { 
  case 0: image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Acco.png"]; break;
  case 1: image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Badm.png"]; break; 
  case 2: image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Book.png"]; break; 
  case 3: image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cafe.png"]; break; 
   
 }
 cell.imageView.image = image;